# Apache http server has stopped working xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am using XAMPP v3.2.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2.
[image]

I have been facing this problem for long time and tried to apply some solution but nothing work. Solution applied as below :

[image]
I need expert help how to solve this problem.

FYI : I am not using Skype in server, Firewall off ,

Comment: Hello! First of all, I would NOT recommend using XAMPP on a production system. It is not configured to be used for that by default. Also: Please do not post images from external resources, because they can disappear and then the whole question wouldn't make any sense to people who want to help or even may have the same issue. Please directly link specific Posts via the link (there is a little "share" link below each question / answer).

Comment: Hi, noted with thanks. Do you have any solution for above problem?